# Functions in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Nodejs and am trying to figure out why I cannot pass the returned value of my function into my function when I call it. Here is my code:

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const http = require("http");
const request = require('request');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const { post } = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const { response } = require('express');
const https = require('follow-redirects').https;


//sets express server vars
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server Connected')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Now serving on ${port} at ${process.env.URI} `)
})


require('dotenv').config();


//authenticate to SpotifyAPI
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.SECRET_ID,
  redirectUri: process.env.URI,
});

const scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email ';
const authUrl = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials';

//Headers needed to auth to SpotifyAPI for Bearer token
const tokenHeaders = {
  'Authorization': process.env.ACCESSTOKEN,
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

};


//spotify Auth Payload
const options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': authUrl,
  'headers': tokenHeaders
};


function accessTokenAuth(bearerToken){
    request(options,  (error, response) => {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    const accessTokenBody = response.body;
    // console.log(accessTokenBody)
    // console.log(request)
    const obj = JSON.parse(accessTokenBody);
    const bearerToken = ("Bearer " + obj.access_token); //add this bearerAuth part to a function to make it repeatable. Times out in 3600???
    // console.log(bearerToken);
    return bearerToken;
});
}
//Add first playlists request using the bearer token

accessTokenAuth(bearerToken);
```

In the function "accessTokenAuth" I create a series of calls that essentially posts data from the above dictionaries into a function that then sends the data to the URL to receive a token back. My question is this, at the bottom of the function when I return "bearerToken", how come I cannot pass "bearerToken" into the function when I call it on line 67. Also, when I comment out calling the function and just run the program it prints out the "bearerToken" when I console.log it in the function. Why is this possible? Aren't you not able to access the function unless it is called?
Thank you!

Comment: Do I have to do that if the only data needed to proceed is the "bearerToken"?

Comment: can you explain to me what the "request" part is that you're talking about? Obviously I wrote it and know what it does but, wouldn't just returning specific data be enough? For example if console.log(bearerToken) it will print the data. If I call the function accessTokenAuth(); it will print the bearer token a second time. Also, how would I return the part you're speaking of?

Comment: right totally get that part. however, when I return bearerToken and go to log it outside the function it says it's undefined.